# "Fahrt" vs. "Reise", "da" vs. "dahin" — when to use which words and do they mean different things?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

I'm doing a German project where I need to write "It was a 14 hour trip there!".

Is the following translation equivalent?

> Es war eine 14-Stunden-Reise dahin!

I'm struggling, for one, with *Reise* and *Fahrt*. What is the difference between the two words? For another, is *dahin* correct or should it be *da*.

Comment: I venture to say that the knowing the difference between *reisen* and *fahren* could help.

Comment: To travel and to drive/go? Reise means journey/trip and Fahrt can also mean trip (as well as a drive). I'm mostly unsure about da vs. dahin.

Comment: *da* is rather there, whilel *dahin* is *in direction of*, I would say.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Would you say that dahin is used correctly in my sentence? Essentially in the sentence I'm saying it was a 14 hour trip in the direction of the city.

Comment: Welcome to this site. For future question, narrow your questions down to **one question**, please. Also show why a dictionary (or Internet research) couldn't answer your question. Both your questions should easily be answered by a dictionary. Finally, this question also needs more context. As you realised yourself, trip can be synynom to journey and drive. We can't know what you meant to say. (But, in fact, once this is resolved, we're back to the dictionary.)

Answer (score 5):

Everything of the following is perfect:

The use of *dahin* is not wrong, but only makes sense in a context with mentioned location, see below. *Fahrt* is used a bit more than *Reise* if the trip was in a car/bus or similar, but none of them is wrong:

> (Car, etc.: generally *Fahrt* is the noun *drive* but also used with ship or balloon for example)
>   Es war eine 14-Stunden-Fahrt. *or*
>   Es war eine 14-stündige Fahrt.
>
> (General: *Reise* is *travel* or *journey*)
>   Es war eine Reise von 14 Stunden. *or*
>   Die Reise [Fahrt/Der Flug] dauerte 14 Stunden.
>
> (Plane: *Flug* is *flight*)
>   Es war ein 14-Stunden-Flug. *or*
>   Es war ein 14-stündiger Flug.

The use of *dahin*, merely a synonym to *dorthin*, is common only, **if the location has been explicitly mentioned before**- especially, if you want to emphasize the location, but isn't it the same with *there*?

> Do you know to which city my boss forced me to drive? Istanbul!.

Then you can use:

> Es war eine 14-stündige Fahrt dahin/dorthin.

*or*  without that precondition:

> Ich war in Istanbul. Es war eine 14-Stunden-Fahrt dahin !

Addition:
Others brought up *da* instead of *dahin*. But *da* as *dort* is only used, if you are already *there* :

> Ich flog erst über London und hatte einen 14-Stunden Aufenthalt da.
>
> Ich hatte eine 14-stündige Reise da.

(The last one is unusual but would mean that you started another trip there where you arrived :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! In my project I went to a place by plane so thank you for also including the flight option. Also, thank you for clarifying dahin for me.

Comment: I just clarified and extended the answer even a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

"It was a 14 hour trip there!".

https://translate.google.com/?sl#auto/de/trip
--> Trip = Ausflug

Ausflug is literally a usually **short** excursion or flying out.

It usually implicates a return on the same day.

So if you want to imply that this was not a short excursion but a long one you can say.

> Unser Ausflug dahin hat 14 Stunden gedauert!

Comment: Werde ich dafür bezahlt? ;)

Comment: Nö, wirst Du nicht, ich aber auch nicht und ich hatte keine Lust, das auseinanderzusortieren. Jetzt sieht's besser aus. Danke.

Answer (score 1):

"Da" refers to location. "Dahin" refers to destination. (And as one of the other posters pointed out, you need to specify the destination before using "dahin.")

Reise literally means "travel" or "journey" rather than "trip," but it is close enough that you can say,  "Es war eine 14-Stunden-Reise dahin!"

As a third poster pointed out, a another translation for "trip" is "Ausflug" but that basically refers to a short "trip." I prefer your translation, above.